# Running Kibana3, LogStash and ElasticSearch, all in one machine

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Kibana3 works successfully when ElasticSearch is in a different machine, by setting `elasticsearch: "http://different_machine_ip:9200"` in config.js of Kibana3.

Now , I want to run all three of them in my local machine for testing. I'm using **Windows7** and using **Chrome** browser. I installed **Kibana 3** on **Tomcat7**. I started the embedded ElasticSearch from **LogStash** jar file. 
I set the ElasticSearch location to `"localhost:9200"` or `"127.0.0.1:9200"` or `"computer_name:9200"`. When I check Kibana3 on the browser, the ElasticSearch query revealed via spying has no logstash index.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200//_search?pretty' -d ''
```

As you can see, the index part is empty, showing `//` only.  The **expected** query should look like this.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/logstash-2013.08.13/_search?pretty' -d 'Some JSON Data'
```

The browser is able to call ElasticSearch API successfully. Example, typing `http://localhost:9200/logstash-2013.08.13/_mapping?pretty=true` on the address bar returns the mapping of logstash index. This proves that there is no probelm in connecting to ElasticSearch.

The problem here is that the index is empty from Kibana query. Why is the index empty?

Comment: Was this question answered for you?

Comment: There were many bugs with the previous logstash versions, at least up to 1.2.0. The last version for now is 1.2.2, which has many bugs removed. Let's hope that it will get even better with the next releases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kibana 3 works differently from Kibana 1 and 2.  It runs entirely in the browser.

The config file is read by javascript and executed in your browser, so localhost:9200 tells Kibana to look for ElasticSearch running on the laptop in front of you, not the server.

BTW - Recent versions of LogStash has Kibana bundled, so you don't have to host it independently.

Comment: Are you saying Kibana3 is bundled with LogStash?

Comment: Yes, since version 1.2.0:  "The old logstash web ui has been replaced by Kibana 3. Kibana is a far superior search and analytics interface."

Comment: Was this actually the issue for you?  This question is still marked unanswered.

Comment: Web UI in logstash 1.2.0 is not working. Hence, I can't confirm whether Kibana3 is bundled or not. Now, I downloaded logstash 1.2.2 but the jar is not working. It could be due to downloading problem as our network is slow right now.

Comment: OK. logstash 1.2.2 is now working. I can see Kibana3 as well. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: And I was scratching my head what's going for two days.. it appears to be my laptop doesn't have ES running.. nice nice..